# inserting mysql data with condition

Tags: php

I have 2 tables the RD (rest day) and the Lessons for inserting a value. 
Looks like this.                        And my second table looks like this

```
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat         Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat          

        RD                           13   13  13  13  13 13
```

How can i validate on second table. If there is a RD on Monday the 13 on second table is 0 meaning no value because the monday is the RD of teacher. Because I'm currently doing a shifting scheduling system of teachers. Here is my insert query

```
include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');
$cewnd = $_POST['cewnd'];
$cewd = $_POST['cewd'];
$cewd = $_POST['cewd'];
$ckwd = $_POST['ckwd'];
$ckwd = $_POST['ckwd'];
$ckwd = $_POST['ckwd'];
$ckwnd = $_POST['ckwnd'];


$query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from t_lessons")or die(mysqli_error());
$count=($query);
if ($count)
{
    echo "<script>document.location='test.php'</script>";
}else{
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO t_lessons(Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat) VALUES('$cewnd','$cewd','$cewd','$cewd','$cewd','$cewd','cewnd ')")or 
        die(mysqli_error($con));
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Successfuly added new Lessons');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location='test.php'</script>";
}

 This is the code of my modal.

    <table border="2" style="float:top; width=10%">
   <thead>
   <tr>
    <th bgcolor="FFFF00">CE Order</th>&nbsp;&nbsp;

   </thead>
   </table>

  <br><table border="2" style="float:top; width=10%">
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>    Day 1- 15<br>
    <input type="text"  name="1sthalf" value="3,500"  required>
    <br>Day 16-<br>
       <input type="text"  name="2ndhalf" value="3,500"  required>
   </th>      </div><!-- /.form group -->


  </thead>
   </table>
    <table border="2" style="float:top; width=10%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="FFFF00">CE Slots</th>&nbsp;&nbsp;

     </thead>

    <table border="2" style="float:top; width=10%"><br>
    <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>    CE Weekday<br>
      <input type="text"  name="cewd" placeholder="0">
      <br>CE Weekend<br>
         <input type="text"  name="cewnd" placeholder="0">
   <br>    CK Weekday<br>
      <input type="text"  name="ckwd" placeholder="0">
      <br>CK Weekend<br>
         <input type="text"  name="ckwnd" placeholder="0">
      <br> <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signup-btn" 
     type="submit" name="add" id="add">
           Add
         </button>
    </th>
   </div><!-- /.form group -->


      </thead>
       </table>
   </table>
```

Comment: so you want that if Mon has RD than nothing insert? Is it right?

Comment: Yes no value is going to insert on Monday on Lessons table. Because I'm developing shifting scheduling system of teacher.

Comment: I just need a validation on my query. I'm searching on net but I can't find what i need. Hope you help me i visit you're profile you have a lot of experience on php.

Comment: hmm, i will solve. One more question what is the values of $_POST['cewd'] and $_POST['ckwd']

Comment: I think this be better on chat but i don't have enough reputation. Can i send you a screen video of my screen? For more clear question please. Do you have facebook?

Comment: you see 3 links --share edit flag below question. Click on edit and in the last you can put the value of those variables, so i can check them.

Comment: buddy im not used fb here.  I want the values of these variables $_POST['cewd'],$_POST['ckwd'],$_POST['ckwnd'].  You are giving me html :(

Comment: Is your rest day table only static values for 7 days or a real calendar with dates attached? It looks like you have only two tables with 7 fields and no dates at all or am I wrong?

Comment: @AnandPandey sorry sir.  for the values for cewd='13' ckwd='13' ckwnd='10' .

Comment: @xander only static values sir. Cause on 7 days the possible value for that is RD (rest day) not the numbers in calendar

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/STO3T.png  this is the link of picture pls view it. So i want to do if there is RD on Monday there must be no value on MONDAY on second table if you can see there is 13 there i want what to be 0. What can i do to make that? Thank you so very much

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7jLO.png this is the my module for adding value. pls click the link

Comment: @phantom: you have to use a unique id in both the tables, without it we cant do like you want.

Comment: So 2 tables need to have a Unique ID? And then what to do next sir?

Comment: @AnandPandey sir? i have now  unique ID in both tables. What to do next?

Comment: @phantom: please define the structure of both tables than i will give you the query.

Comment: @AnandPandey The structure of table for RD [Sun=[varchar],Mon=[varchar],Tue=[varchar],Wed=[varchar],Thu=[varchar],Fri=[varchar],Sat=[varchar] and for Lessons table where in the value of lesson store [Sun=[varchar],Mon=[varchar],Tue=[varchar],Wed=[varchar],Thu=[varchar],Fri=[varchar],Sat=[varchar . If you see the structure of two tables is the same. Any suggestion sir how to improve this and get my desired output? You can check link i provided on top that's my interface. Thank you so much

Comment: @AnandPandey help me pls.

Comment: Sorry yesterday i was suffered from fever buddy. Please check my answer below

Comment: @AnandPandey I'll check this sir. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

After some time, i have successfully manage to validate the insert query. Please made the same column name (if not same on both tables).

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database= "mydemo";

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);

if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : ".mysqli_error());
}
// Set the active mySQL database
$dbselected = mysqli_select_db($connection,$database);

if (!$dbselected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysqli_error());
}

function build_sql_insert($table, $data,$con) {
    $key = array_keys($data);
    $val = array_values($data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(', ', $key) . ") "
         . "VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $val) . "')";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    return($res);
}

// Here you select data from the table rd so you get which columns has "RD" value 
$result=mysqli_query($connection,"select sun,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat from rd") or die(mysqli_error());
$arr1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
// In below there is some modification perform so it fit on your need
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$v){
    if(strlen($v)){
        $temp[$k] = 0;
    }
}

// This is your array which is need to be manage by you. Here i write some static values but you have to manage it.
$arr2 = array(
    'sun'=> 10, 
    'mon'=> 14,
    'tue'=> 14,
    'wed'=> 14,
    'thur'=> 14,
    'fri'=> 14,
    'sat'=> 10
);

$finalarr = array_merge($arr2,$temp);
//Here is $connection has the connection object. 'lesson' is the table name and $finalarr is the array which we made to insert
$resi = build_sql_insert('lesson', $finalarr,$connection);
if($resi ==1){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        alert('Successfuly added new Lessons');</script>";
    echo "<script>document.location='test.php'</script>";
}

?>
```

And cheers! Your problem has been solve.

Comment: I'm gonna check this sir Thank you!

Comment: Sir i have a question on this code.  }

function build_sql_insert($table, $data,$con) {
    $key = array_keys($data);
    $val = array_values($data);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table (" . implode(', ', $key) . ") "
         . "VALUES ('" . implode("', '", $val) . "')";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    return($res);
}                                           Do i have to modify it? Or that's it no more modification needed? Because I think i need to call my table and values

Comment: Here i use 2 tables rd and lesson you can change as your tables name.

Comment: Hi sir. I'm getting bulk of errors. Can you please show me the output on your pc? Thank you so much . And the complete codes . I think I'm missing something . I'm sorry sir I'm very stress here on my work cause I developing the system alone.

Comment: @phantom: Its tested code you just need to change the tables data in it. You are developer and you have to find things yourself. I know it stress sometimes but you have to solve yourself i cant put my screen here.